# Send variable from PHP to HTML

Tags: php, html

I am sending HTML form variable to php script, where php checks variables, now i need to send another variable back to HTML. Is there any way?

```html
<form action="login.php">
Login: <input type=text size=16 name="nick"><br>
<br>
Heslo:  <input type=password size=16 name="pass"><br>
<br>
<input type=submit value="login">
</form>
```

This is form in HTML, now i need to get in same HTML page variable from php.

Comment: You can set a `$_SESSION` when posting to `login.php`.

Comment: Please read about `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

First set the action to `?`. This sents the sumbit to the same page. Then create a `method` attribute to set the method to set the data. I would advise POST because you're sending a password. (read more about [form methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp))

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
Login:  <input type=text size=16 name="nick"><br>
<br>
Heslo:  <input type=password size=16 name="pass"><br>
<br>
<input type=submit value="login">
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['nick']) AND isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $nick = $_POST['nick'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; 

    /* print data */
    print_r($nick);
    print_r($pass);
  }
?>
```